# How to send Data over FTP(user: password) using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, ftp, nsurlsession

I have checked some old post about achieving this but have not found solution yet. I want to know if possible to do this without using third party framework. If NSURLSession can be help full. I have tried as below but going as unsupported URL error:

error submitting request: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7feb907f2a80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ftp.name.com, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL})

My code:
let urlString = "ftp.name.com"

```
    let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: xmlFile.stringValue)

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let userPasswordString = "user:password"

    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"

    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)


    if let percentURLString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
    {

    let url = NSURL(string: percentURLString )


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = fileData

        print("FTP Request :\(request)")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:
    {
        (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("error submitting request: \(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        {
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200
            {
                print("response was not 200: \(response)")
                return
            }

            else if httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            {
                print("FIle sent")
            }
        }

        })


    task.resume()


    }
```

}

Comment: Find a good third party framework and see how they implement FTP.

Comment: And you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926083/ios-ftp-upload-using-nsurlsession

Comment: Is there any way to convert FTP Url into HTTP? So I can use NSURLSession to perform upload.

Comment: No, they are two completely different protocols.

Comment: Hi there, is there any third party framework for FTP transfer with SWIFT?? I can't find any , its all using CFNetwork with Deprecated methods.